# Find product of two sine waves in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the solution to the post of [tikz plot of two sine waves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201943/tikz-plot-of-two-sine-waves-showing-the-phase-difference), I was trying to modify the code to include the product of the two signals.  How do you code the product of the two signals?  I tried as an initial attempt to just do the sum of the signals, however, I did not get an output. Can you help me get the product of the two signals?  Thanks!

Here is the code with slight modification to add the sum of the two signals:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0-pi/6}
\FPeval\XMax{2*pi}
\FPeval\YMin{0-3/2}
\FPeval\YMax{5/2}

\FPeval\XOL{0-1/2} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/2} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0-1/5} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/5} % of DeltaY

\FPset\xTrigLabelBase{6}
\FPeval\yTrigLabelBase{pi}
\FPset\Dx{1}
\FPset\Dy{1}

\FPeval\dx{pi/xTrigLabelBase*Dx}
\FPeval\dy{pi/yTrigLabelBase*Dy}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+dx*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+dx*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+dy*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+dy*YOT}


\newlength\Width\Width=12cm
\newlength\Height\Height=8cm

\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    xtrigLabels=true,
    %ytrigLabels=true,
    xtrigLabelBase=\xTrigLabelBase,
    %ytrigLabelBase=\yTrigLabelBase,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=500,
}

\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
        dx=\dx,
        dy=\dy,
        %Dx=\Dx,
        %Dy=\Dy,
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickwidth=.4pt,
        subtickwidth=.2pt,
        tickcolor=Red!30,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen!30,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
}

\def\f{sin(x)}
\def\g{sin(x+Pi/6)}
\def\h{sin(x) + sin(x+Pi/6)}


\begin{document}
\pslegend[rt]{%
    \color{NavyBlue}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{NavyBlue} $y=\sin x$ \\
    \color{Red}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{Red} $y=\sin(x+\pi/6) x$
}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\dx,
        dy=\dy,
        Dx=\Dx,
        Dy=\Dy,
        linecolor=gray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
        axespos=top,
    ]{<->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}%{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psaxes[style=mygrid](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{\XMin}{\XMax}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=Red]{\XMin}{\XMax}{\g}
    \psplot[linecolor=Cyan]{\XMin}{\XMax}{\h}
    \pcline[linestyle=dashed,offset=.5,linecolor=Magenta]{|*-|*}(*{Pi 3 div} {\f})(*{Pi 2 div} {\g})\naput{ $\scriptstyle\Delta x = \tfrac{\pi}{6}$}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is PSTricks. You want the pgfplots equal?

Comment: Sure, I think that I can work with pgfplots!  Thanks.

Comment: @percusse, Hello, any luck with the pgfplots implementation of my MWE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution using the `datavisulization` library from `tikz`. For creating the `pi`-based `x-axis` i used a custom `tick typesetter` as described under **77.4.11** in the [pgfmanual](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

In your question you asked about the sum **and** the product for the functions. Because i was not sure which one you really need, i plotted both. Also your plot label shows the function `g` gets an additional `* x` whereas your function definition of `g` does not perform this calculation. If you need the `* x` in the functions you can adjust the following code to your needs.

> Updated version with minor grid as requested per comment

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions, arrows}

\def\mytypesetter#1{
  \pgfmathparse{#1/pi}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
  \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
  }{
    \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac, frac denom=6, frac whole=false]{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [
      school book axes,
      all axes={
        grid={
          major={style={red!50!black, opacity=.25}},        
          minor={style={green!25!black, opacity=.25}},
          minor steps between steps=4,
      }},
      x axis={
        label=$x$,
        ticks and grid={
          stack,
          step=(pi/6),
          tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},
      }},
      y axis={
        label=$y$, 
        grid={step=1}
      },
      style sheet=vary hue,
      visualize as line/.list={sin1, sin2, prod, sum},
      sin1={label in legend={text={$\sin(x)$}}},
      sin2={label in legend={text={$\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$}}},
      prod={label in legend={text={$\sin(x) \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$}}},
      sum={label in legend={text={$\sin(x) + \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$}}},
    ]
    data [set=sin1, format=function] {
      var x : interval [-pi/6:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin(\value x r);
    }
    data [set=sin2, format=function] {
      var x : interval [-pi/6:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin((\value x + pi/6)r);
    }
    data [set=prod, format=function] {
      var x : interval [-pi/6:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin(\value x r) * sin((\value x + pi/6)r);
    }
    data [set=sum, format=function] {
      var x : interval [-pi/6:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin(\value x r) + sin((\value x + pi/6)r);    
    };

    \draw [{Bar[]}-{Bar[]}, thick, dashed] (2*pi/6,1.25) -- ++(pi/6,0) node [above, midway] {\scriptsize $\Delta x = \frac{\pi}{6}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: `\sin(x)` not `sin(x)`, that way the operator is typeset upright as it should be.

Comment: thx, changed it.

Comment: @moospit, Thanks for your solution.  How do I go about getting the grid like in the original MWE?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe see my updated answer