# Use tikz to plot sine wave with text and lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to get a tikz plot to look like:

[image]

I am getting two cycles in my code.  The original code was masterfully written by [moospit found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288237/find-product-of-two-sine-waves-in-tikz).  Here is the code to start with:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions, arrows}

\def\mytypesetter#1{
  \pgfmathparse{#1/pi}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
  \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
  }{
    \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac, frac whole=false]{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [
      school book axes,
      all axes={
        grid={
          major={style={red!50!black, opacity=.25}},
          minor={style={green!25!black, opacity=.25}},
          minor steps between steps=3,
      }},
      x axis={
        label=$\phi$,
        ticks and grid={
          stack,
          step=(2*pi),
          tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},
      }},
      y axis={
        label=$v$,
        grid={step=1}
      },
      style sheet=vary hue,
      visualize as line/.list={sin1}
    ]
    data [set=sin1, format=function] {
      var x : interval [-2*pi:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin(\value x r);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the `interval [-2*pi:2*pi]` to whatever you prefer ?

Comment: Or do you mean that you don't really want to plot that function but a different one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the `datavisualization` of tikz. So I recreated your picture with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=6cm,
        width=13cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        domain={-360:360},
        ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
        xmin=-400, xmax=400,
        major tick length=1ex,
        minor tick length=0pt,
        tick style={color=black,thin},
        xtick={-360, 360},
        xticklabels={$-2\pi$, $2\pi$},
        minor xtick={-360,-270,...,360},
        xlabel=$\phi$,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=west,
        },
        xticklabel shift={.2cm},
        ytick={-1,1},
        yticklabels={$-1$, $1$},
        minor ytick={-0.5,0.5},
        ylabel=$v$,
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=south,
        },
        ]
    \addplot[thin, dashed] coordinates { (80, 0) (80, 0.642788) (0, 0.642788) };
    \addplot[thick, black, samples=100] { sin(0.5*x) };
    \addplot+[mark=*, color=black, mark options={scale=0.75,fill=black}] coordinates { (80, 0.642788) };
    \node at (axis cs:0,0.642788) [anchor=east] {$\sigma_v$};
    \node at (axis cs:80,0) [anchor=north] {$\sigma_\phi$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Output:**

[image: pgfplots]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  How do you go about adding the gridlines like that found in the original code?  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe I added the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

[image: another function]

That's not `sin x`, though.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions, arrows}

\def\mytypesetter#1{
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
  \pgfmathparse{#1/pi}
  \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$%}
  }{
    \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac, frac whole=false]{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [
      school book axes,
      all axes={
        grid={
          major={style={red!50!black, opacity=.25}},
          minor={style={green!25!black, opacity=.25}},
          minor steps between steps=3,
      }},
      x axis={
        label=$\phi$,
        ticks and grid={
          stack,
          step=(2*pi),
          tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},
      }},
      y axis={
        label=$v$,
        grid={step=1}
      },
      style sheet=vary hue,
      visualize as line/.list={sin1}
    ]
    data [set=sin1, format=function] {
      var x : interval [-2*pi:2*pi] samples 100;
      func y = sin(\value x/2 r);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.  How do I go about putting in the lines for \sigma v, and \sigma \phi?  Thanks again.

Comment: You could just use the ready-made **pgfplots** solution offered in the other answer. Or I guess it must be possible to annotate this. Do you need the `datavisualization` solution?

Comment: with the pgfplots, how can you add the grid lines in the background?